# Does there exist a vector field on the torus $T^2$ whose zeros consist of precisely one saddle and one source?

Tags: differential-topology, vector-fields

This question is motivated by the statement in "Differential Topology", by Guillemin and Pollack, page 133:

> Patterns admissible on the torus, like one saddle plus one source, are prohibited on the sphere.

Here, *patterns* refers to the behaviour of a vector field about its zeros.
Of course, using the Euler Characteristic, we can rule out the existence of such a vector field on the sphere, however it is not clear to me whether such a vector field exists on the torus.

Comment: [Image](http://www.vis.uni-stuttgart.de/~bachthsn/projects/vectorvis/torus_oglic.png)

Comment: @Hellen I have tried to draw this more precisely, and I get [this](https://photos.app.goo.gl/ChfaGypzQfZpNy4u2). Assuming I am correct, the flow lines into / out of the saddle (in my diagram, these are the edges of the square) cannot be oriented consistently. Can you provide more detail?